# error C2061: syntax error : identifier

Tags: c++, syntax-error

Here is my C++ code

```
// XuatChuoiBTHang.h
#pragma once
#include "BieuThuc.h"
#include "BieuThucHang.h"

class XuatChuoiBTHang
{
    public:
        virtual string xuatChuoi(BieuThucHang* btHang) = 0;     
};

// BieuThucHang.h
#pragma once
#include "bieuthuc.h"
#include "XuatChuoiBTHang.h"

class BieuThucHang : public BieuThuc
{
    private:
        XuatChuoiBTHang* xuatChuoiBTHang;
};
```

Ouput is:

> **"error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BieuThucHang' "**

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 40):

You have a circular dependency of header files. You need to break this circular inclusion dependency by 
using a forward declaration in `XuatChuoiBTHang.h`:

```
class BieuThucHang;
```

Also, remove `#include "BieuThucHang.h"` from `XuatChuoiBTHang.h`.

Comment: Tell him about the circular dependency before someone else posts another answer.

Comment: Tell him he shall use header quardian as well :)

Comment: yeah, can you suggest me something about circular dependency ?
Thank u very much !

Comment: @DungLe: Well you cannot learn C++ on a programming forum So my suggestion is to pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). For immediate understanding [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) might be useful.

Comment: In a method of class BieuThuc, I wrote:
`this->xuatChuoiBTHang->xuatChuoi(this);`
and the ouput is "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed". So how to fix it ?

Comment: @DungLe - If you have another question, please post that as a new question.